# Page does not change when navigating forward from second page to third page, which is the first page with the same url as the third page Angular Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Example, my route way is like this : page A (first) -> page B -> page A (second)

Routing from page A (first) to B works fine. But, when routing page B to A (second), the page is showing the same condition as page A (first).

I thought angular reuses page A (second) with page A (first). How to make the router to create new page for page A (second)?

*using RouteReuseStrategy or not, it still didn't work

Comment: Do not set the route reuse strategy ? Also more context is required, maybe you're momoizing some state in a service ? Try producing a [mcve] showing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the objective is to recreate Page A by navigating to it again you can [kill the previous route](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#replaceUrl) when navigating to Page B.

```
this.router.navigate(["pageb"], {replaceUrl:true});
```

if you want to keep several different page A you will need to [use a parameter along your route](https://www.samjulien.com/how-to-use-route-parameters-in-angular)

```
{path: 'pagea/:param', component: Pagea }
```